# SWT layout selection

Tags: layout, swt

I'm trying to make a box that allows you to select some variables, and re-order the ones that are selected. So the LEFT box starts filled, the RIGHT box starts empty. You move items from the left to the right, and on the right you can re-arrange their order (with the up and down buttons). This lets you pick what items you want and in what order (for sorting purposes in another section of the program).

The layout I'm going for looks like of like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, it's coming out like... well... :-(

[image]

The functionality I'm looking for all works. Yay. I am just having a very hard time with the layout. I think if I can reach the following four primary objectives, I'll be set.

1. How can I get the OK and CANCEL buttons on the bottom instead of above the multis?
2. How can I get the multis to have a pre-set size (let's say... 10)
3. How can I get the arrow buttons to be stacked vertically instead of horizontally?
4. How can I get the arrow buttons to be between the two multis?

I figure each of these particular objectives are probably one-liners, perhaps a little bit of plumbing here and there...

On a side note, I'm using GridLayout - this might be a poor choice. Is there a better choice for something like this?

Without further ado, here's the code that generates this horrid mess...

```
    @Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    parent.getShell().setText("Multi-sort");

    Composite dialogcomp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    dialogcomp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    available = new List(getShell(), SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    for(String t : MultiSortDialog.availableNames) {
        available.add(t);
    }
    used = new List(getShell(), SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    for(String t : MultiSortDialog.usedNames) {
        used.add(t);
    }
    createButton(parent, ADD, ">", false);
    createButton(parent, REM, "<", false);
    createButton(parent, UP, "^", false);
    createButton(parent, DOWN, "V", false);

    return dialogcomp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would suggest you simple use the `Dialog`'s default OK and Cancel buttons and not trying to lay out your own.  SWT has a nice system for placing them in the system default location (i.e., on Mac OS, the OK button will be on the right, which is the correct location.)
2. Don't use `Dialog.createButton()` to create buttons.  This creates a button on your dialog which, although it sounds like what you want to do, actually isn't.  This creates a button in the style of OK or Cancel buttons, expected to be placed in the button bar composite that the `Dialog` class owns and styled appropriately for the bottom row OK/Cancel buttons.  You want to create a new Button in the composite you're creating.  That is:

```java
    Button addButton = new Button(dialogcomp, SWT.PUSH);
    addButton.setText(">");
    addButton.addSelectionListener(...);
```

1. To stack the buttons vertically, create a new composite inside `dialogcomp` to contain them.
2. To put the arrow buttons between the `List`s, you need to ensure that you add things in the correct order.  With a `GridLayout`, you need to add widgets in the order that you want them to appear.

Other points:

1. Don't change the title of the dialog by calling `Shell.setText()`.  Call `setText()` in your
2. Don't try to parent your `List`s inside the parent shell.  You're given a composite to put things in.  This will wreak havoc on your layouts.  You're basically hoisting widgets up into things you don't own and don't layout.  Instead, put it in the `Composite` you created.
3. You may also wish to create buttons with the type `SWT.ARROW | SWT.LEFT` instead of simply drawing a `<` sign.  It may be more visually appealing.  Just something to investigate.

A simple rearrangement of your code, creating `Button`s properly, and creating a new composite to hold the buttons, will get you much closer:

```java
Composite dialogcomp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
dialogcomp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

available = new List(dialogcomp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
for(String t : MultiSortDialog.availableNames) {
    available.add(t);
}

Composite buttonComposite = new Composite(dialogcomp, SWT.NONE);
buttonComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

Button addButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
addButton.setText(">");

Button removeButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
removeButton.setText("<");

Button upButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
upButton.setText("^");

Button downButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
downButton.setText("v");

used = new List(dialogcomp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
for(String t : MultiSortDialog.usedNames) {
    used.add(t);
}
```

This will probably get you pretty close to what you want.  However, you will probably want to apply `GridData`s for each of your instances.  For example, your two `List`s will probably want to grab and fill horizontally and vertically to fill the layout as the `Dialog` is resized.  But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Exercise for the reader is fine by me. This is exactly what I was looking for, even without your code! The simple points make this an excellent answer. The code snippet is just icing on the cake. Thank you so much! I'll be sure to let you know how things turned out. :-)

Comment: yay for working on the weekend. This was a giant help. A couple notes - I used dialogcomp as `used`'s parent instead of getShell(), and fixed the text for the remove button (which had to be flipped). I added selection listeners that just called my already-written-working-and-tested method for their behavior. I still need to add the default OK and Cancel buttons (which I was using before, but had never actually turned them on...) but aside from that it's working like a charm. Thank you so very much for taking the time to explain the thought process - it's worth 10x more than the code!!

Comment: something I don't see is objective #2. I can't find a way to easily say "Make both of these Lists be visible for 10 rows." Any thoughts?

Comment: Good catch on the text for `removeButton` and the parent for `used`.  As for height hints, you can set a `GridData` with `heightHint` in pixels.  If you want estimates on a height in characters, you'll have to build a `GC` and measure the string extent of the `List`'s font, then multiply by the number of lines you want.  It's not perfect (it doesn't take into account any margins/padding your OS adds) but it's pretty close and a handy utility method to have around.

Comment: Edward, that is indeed perfect. I just made it a little too big to err on the side of caution and it looks fine. The key thing, even if they have to scroll, is that the right and left are the same size. That's very important. I can't thank you enough for the assistance you've provided. It doesn't just solve the problems I had here, but it helps me understand the mindset it takes to create these layouts. Thanks again!